# Issue with Facebook Activity Feed plugin on my website

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have used face book recent activity script in my website,But it does not show anything in side the box where the script is placed,even I have feeds from my friend list.

Here is the code what I have used :

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/activity.php?site=http%3A%2F%2Fintegration.mytaste.com.au%2F&amp;width=300&amp;height=300&amp;header=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;border_color&amp;recommendations=false" 
    scrolling="no" 
    frameborder="0" 
    style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:300px;" 
    allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

you can just test it from here itself

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/

use this url http://integration.mytaste.com.au/ for domain field in the box.

Comment: have any of your Facebook friends used any of the Facebook features on your site yet, such as Liking something or sharing a post?

Comment: Yes, one of my friend who has been added as a friend in face book has liked some posts in the website recently, but there were no feeds have been shown.

Comment: It is  not working well for a particular domain if i use any other domain it's working well.

Comment: I am facing same problem on my website developed in drupal!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you have any Open Graph tags on any of the pages on your site. Check out the [Open Graph Protocol documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) and add at least the og:title, og:type, og:url, and og:image meta tags to your pages to have them start showing up in the [Activity Feed plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/). You can use the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to ensure your pages are getting scraped correctly by us.

P.S. The auto-posting to a user's wall when they click your Like button is sort of misleading and could be called out as such by our Policy team (check out the [policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)). I would suggest you just use the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) instead. It has the added benefit of giving social context even if the user isn't logged in to your site. If you need to detect when a user has liked something on your site, you can subscribe to the "edge.create" event using [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) in the Javascript SDK.